# Hover image size issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used hover images but when I opened it on small screen {400px, 969px } those images are overflowing, it's not fit with devices. I tried with x overflow but its chopping the image. I need those images to fit all devices with

```css
*, *::before, *::after{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hero2 container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}

figure{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
  margin: auto;
}

figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

figcaption div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

figcaption div:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

figure img{       
  flex: auto;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
          transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        width: 100%;
}

figure:hover figcaption{
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

figcaption:hover div{
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}

figcaption:hover div:after{
  width: 50%;
}

figure:hover img{
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
          transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);     
}

.grid {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 1em 0 4em;
 max-width: 1000px;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

/*font-face*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Lato Hairline'), local('Lato-Hairline'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/boeCNmOCCh-EWFLSfVffDg.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/KT3KS9Aol4WfR6Vas8kNcg.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/9k-RPmcnxYEPm8CNFsH2gg.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/wkfQbvfT_02e2IWO3yYueQ.woff) format('woff');
}

.hero2 p {
    font-size: 50;
}
    
.hero2 row content container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0%;
  flex: auto;   
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="test1.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"> 
<div class="hero2">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="ie=edge"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <body>
       <div class="row content">  
         <p> Projects  </p>
           <div class="container">
  <figure>
    <img src="online%20shoping.jpg" alt="Thumb"width="300" height=" 300" />
      <figcaption><div>  Online shoping site <br>  Technology: Java , SQL <br>
               Web-based online shopping application . It maintains the details of customer payments, product receipts, products and also updating, deletion for the same.  It also stores the details of invoices generated by customer and payments details. The primary features of the project are high accuracy, design flexibility and easy availability.  </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="hexapod.jpg" alt="Thumb" width="300" height=" 300" />
      <figcaption><div>      Hexapod Robot       <br>Technology: Embedded                  This project develops a Hexapod robot used to explore a remote location by sensing the parameters like light, temperature, distance etc, processes it and transmits the collected data to the control station using wireless means. Here Wi-Fi technology was used, real time video capturing facility.                                     </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  
  <figure>
    <img src="per.JPG" alt="Thumb" width="300" height=" 300"/>
      <figcaption><div> dipuraj.com- Personal website            </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  
  <figure>
    <img src="autonom.jpg"   alt="Thumb" width="300" height=" 300" />
      <figcaption><div>Machine learning project   Technology: JAVA, SQL <br>
  Getting  the true data and after making  real time examples it will be used to teach the machine , how to react with situations occurring around it. For getting the perfect output we analysed it through several stages after the development.           </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  
           </div></div>
       </body>
       
       </div>
```

[screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2vqV.jpg) hover effect[output what I got [what I am expecting in all screen (small mobile device below 400 res)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVTIp.jpg)

hope that I will get a solution from someone

Answer (score 0):

You have not used media query to fit in different device , Since you have followed the same `css` for all the device you should not specify the `width` and `height` for figure instead try using `max-width` and `max-height`

```
figure{
  max-width: 400px; /* Corrected css */
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

If you specify `width` in all device the given `width` will be applied unless you have written `media query` to apply different `width` for different devives.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the width and height given to the  tag inside your html and specify it through css to maintain the height and width of the image to fit the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It will Help you try to define your width and height of window like

```
window.innerWidth;
window.innerHeight;
```

In java script and set your image size width and height with %.
For more help [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
change figure width:400px; into width:100%;

```
figure{
       width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used media query with calculation for width now you can check. when your device width is less than 600 you will get full view of your image for device width above 600 you will see two split of your image panel.

```css
*, *::before, *::after{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}



.hero2   container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;

}






figure{
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
  margin: auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  figure{
   width: calc(100% - 5px);
   height: 300px;
  }
}

figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

figcaption div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

figcaption div:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

figure img{ 
    
    flex: auto;
    float:left;
   margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
          transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
          transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
        width: 100%;
}

figure:hover figcaption{
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

figcaption:hover div{
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}

figcaption:hover div:after{
  width: 50%;
}

figure:hover img{
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
          transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1);
      
 
}

.grid {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 1em 0 4em;
 max-width: 1000px;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}


/*font-face*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Lato Hairline'), local('Lato-Hairline'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/boeCNmOCCh-EWFLSfVffDg.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/KT3KS9Aol4WfR6Vas8kNcg.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/9k-RPmcnxYEPm8CNFsH2gg.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/lato/v6/wkfQbvfT_02e2IWO3yYueQ.woff) format('woff');
}
.hero2 p
{
    font-size: 50;
}

    
.hero2 row content container{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0%;
flex: auto;
   
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="test1.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"> 
<div class="hero2">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"content="ie=edge"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <body>
       <div class="row content">
          
       
  <p> Projects  </p>
<div class="container">
 
  <figure>
    <img src="online%20shoping.jpg" alt="Thumb" />
      <figcaption><div>  Online shoping site <br>  Technology: Java , SQL <br>
               Web-based online shopping application . It maintains the details of customer payments, product receipts, products and also updating, deletion for the same.  It also stores the details of invoices generated by customer and payments details. The primary features of the project are high accuracy, design flexibility and easy availability.  </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  <figure>
    <img src="hexapod.jpg" alt="Thumb" />
      <figcaption><div>      Hexapod Robot       <br>Technology: Embedded                  This project develops a Hexapod robot used to explore a remote location by sensing the parameters like light, temperature, distance etc, processes it and transmits the collected data to the control station using wireless means. Here Wi-Fi technology was used, real time video capturing facility.                                     </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  
  <figure>
    <img src="per.JPG" alt="Thumb" />
      <figcaption><div> dipuraj.com- Personal website            </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  
  <figure>
    <img src="autonom.jpg"   alt="Thumb" />
      <figcaption><div>Machine learning project   Technology: JAVA, SQL <br>
  Getting  the true data and after making  real time examples it will be used to teach the machine , how to react with situations occurring around it. For getting the perfect output we analysed it through several stages after the development.           </div></figcaption>
  </figure>
  
  
           </div></div>
       </body>
       
       </div>
```